# How to extend a metric defined by an injective function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose we have a metric space (X,d), and another set Y. If there is an injective function $f$ from X to Y. We can construct a metric on the image of Y: $d(y_{1},y_{2}) = d(f^{-1}(y_{1}),d^{-1}(y_{2}))$, and I want to extend this metric to other elements in Y that are not in the image.

> 1. I think if we assume the Image of f with this metric has finite diameter M, setting $d(a,b)=M+1$ if $a \notin Im(f) \lor b \notin Im(f)$ should suffice, is this correct?
> 2. However, in general, I'm not sure how can we extend this metric. Can we always extend it?

I felt that someone should have asked this question given how simple it is, but I did not find any posts. Please let me know if this is already asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is empty the problem is trivial.  Assume $y\in {\rm Im}(f)$.  Then for $a\notin{\rm Im}(f)$ and $b\in {\rm Im}(f)$ define:$$
d(a,b)=1+d(y,b).$$
Also set $d(a,b)=1$ if $a,b\notin {\rm Im}(f)$, $a\neq b$.